# Is it possible to use computer effectively without mouse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Sorry if this question is a bit onff-topic here. I am just a newbie in using computer shortcut/hotkeys. I am wondering if you can use computer effectively fast without using the mouse. Are you mostly use keyboard shortcuts/hotkeys?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome (out) on Superuser. Your question is probably getting closed because opinion based. Nothing personal. Give a look to the page [ask]. It depends from the use you will do. Some applications are planned for the mouse. Some other for keyboard. Linux, many programming environments, all the word processors are historical keyboard friendly. Windows mouse friendly. The shells keyboard again. Learn all the keyboard shortcuts, you will go faster and you will develop your way of working consequently.

Comment: Thank you for your kind. I am trying some keyboard shortcuts I learned here such as "Ctrl +L" and I enjoy it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but it depends on what type of applications you intend on using (are they keyboard friendly and have a standard set of keyboard shortcuts on them). Most of them can be used with only a keyboard. It also takes some time to get used to it.

For a list of default windows shortcuts you can read more about it here

[Keyboard  shortcuts  for Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/126449)

and here

[How to navigate Windows using a keyboard](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000791.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a computer without touching a mouse is entirely possible, if not preferable. I do it often while programming. This being said, I making heavy use of the following:

- [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/): to create custom, system wide hotkeys and hotstrings.
- [Batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) files (often triggered by AHK scripts) to execute complicated sequences of actions.
- [DOSKEY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSKEY): to create custom CMD commands to shorten complicated functions.